# How to normalize the data rate (job run time / bytes read & written during job execution) value measured on different machines?

Tags: io, statistics, benchmarking

The machines may have different number of CPUs, different load and different RAM sizes.
In that case how do i normalize the data rate values obtained so that i can tell a particular system is better IO capable than the other?
Can anyone tell me in detail ?

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: Why don't you just ask your OS to give you this kind of information?

Comment: How do i get the load info from OS ? Is i number of process running ? Assume i have the info from OS how do i normalize the data rate across machines ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can normalize this for an arbitrary "job". How much of the job is CPU bound? How much is I/O bound? The overall CPU load on a machine may not matter if job mainly reading from a file. RAM size only matters when you need a lot of it, and your OS may put limits on how much may be allocated to a single process, so the total amount of RAM on a system is irrelevant.

If you want to measure the I/O capabilities of a system, write (or find) some benchmarks that measure I/0-bound operations (e.g. that continuously write chunks of various sizer to disk, or send data through a socket, etc) and run them on the system under it's normal operation (i.e. when it's not doing an anti virus scan or downloading updates). The results you get should be comparable without the need to normalize them (though they'll will obviously be subject to variation, so you'll need to do several runs on each system and then look at the means and standard deviations).